# Cut string at complete word closest to certain character number

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to split a vector of strings into two pieces (I only want to keep the first bit) based on the following criteria:

- it should split after a full word (i.e. where a space occurs)
- it should cut at the space closest to the 12th character

Example:

```
textvec <- c("this is an example", "I hope someone can help me", "Thank you in advance")
```

Expected result is a vector like this:

```
"this is an" , "I hope someone", "Thank you in"
```

What I tried so far:
I'm able to get the full words that occur before or at the 12th character like this:

```
t13 <- substr(textvec , 1, 13) #gives me first 13 characters of each string
lastspace <- lapply(gregexpr(" ", t13), FUN=function(x) x[length(x)]) #gives me last space before/at 13th character
result <- substr(t13, start=1, stop=lastspace)
```

But what I want is to get include the word closest to the 12th character (e.g. "someone" in the example above), not necessarily before or at the 12th character. In case there's a tie, I would like to include the word after the 12th character. I hope I'm explaining myself clearly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cumsum`,

```
sapply(strsplit(textvec, ' '), function(i) paste(i[cumsum(nchar(i)) <= 12], collapse = ' '))

#[1] "this is an"     "I hope someone" "Thank you in"
```

Comment: Thanks! Although Akrun's answer also worked for the example I gave, I'm accepting this answer because it also includes the final word in case the character string is shorter than 12.

Comment: That's pretty neat!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gregexpr` to find the closest space at 12 and then with `substr` cut the string

```
substr(textvec, 1, sapply(gregexpr("\\s+", textvec), 
            function(x) x[which.min(abs(12 - x))])-1)
#[1] "this is an"     "I hope someone" "Thank you in"
```

Comment: Here's my answer which was too similar: `lapply(textvec, function(x) substr(x, 1, unlist(gregexpr(" ", x))[which.min(abs(12 - unlist(gregexpr(" ", x))))] - 1))`